# WPF button Visual State on press, keep the visual state "running" after button loses focus

Tags: wpf, button

Im working with wpf c# Window.
 I have a button defined like this:

```
<Button x:Name="but" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle13}" / >
```

and my ButtonStyle is this:

```
<VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
 //bla bla (my style) goes here
```

Now, when I use this kind of visual state, when the button is pressed the visual is changing but then goes back to normal. I want the button to have a "pressed" condition, where it will stay "pressed" until i press another button.

I tried changing it like this:

```
<VisualState x:Name="myPre">
```

and then within code to use:

```
 VisualStateManager.GoToElementState(but, "myPre", true);
```

Wich dosent work at all. I then used

```
 VisualStateManager.GoToState(but, "myPre", true);
```

This makes my button pressed as long as the mouse is over the button, but when it losts focus (mouse moves) it goes back to normal.

I hope ive been clear.
How can I make the button stay in visual state of pressed untill I decides (within code) to cancel that?

Answer (score 6):

If you need `Button` which will stay in pressed state after pressing on it - then use `ToggleButton`.

`<ToggleButton IsChecked='True'/>`

Answer (score 0):

As I can see it has been a while since the question but it's exactly the same problem that I have. The answer from Anatolii Gabuza put me on the right track.
I don't know if that was there before, but there is now the following possibility.

```xml
<VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
        <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
          <Storyboard>
            <... do some Animation.. >
          </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked" />
        <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate" />
      </VisualStateGroup>
```

In the msdn there is the following explanation:
[MSDN-Article ToggleButton Styles and Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/togglebutton-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)